# Twitter stream for website

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter

I've made a few twitter streams in the past using a few lines of code and styled it up to suit my needs. But since the twitter API change I've become a little confused how it works now.

I have read through the dev pages of the twitter site and it says you should now create a widget for your website.

When creating the widget you must be log in to the users twitter and create a new widget, I'm designing a website and don't have the users twitter currently.

I see wordpress themes and plugins that have twitter streams without needing to create a widget, all you do is enter your username and it works. This is how I used to do it in the past with a few lines of code and a username.

I'm wondering if someone could reference me to a page or show me the "new" way to create a twitter stream for a website without having to create a widget each time.

Hope that makes sense!
Thanks.

Comment: The old way should still work, AFAIK the new 1.1 REST API won't replace the old one before sometime in March.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have just tried the following demo http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/ and still seems to work. Works fine for me anyway. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can create widget with any account. Only thing is that the widget should not be deleted from that account once it is implemented on site. You can later make widget from users account and copy paste the code from there. After which you can delete that widget from your account. But remember, widget will not work/shown if you delete it from the twitter account from which you have copy pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried the following demo remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step and still seems to work. Works fine for me anyway. Cheers